# istio AuthorizationPolicy deny rule question

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I defined the following first policy to deny all requests to workload1 in namespace foo unless they come from workload2 or workload3
I get RBAC: access denied when trying to access from workload2 to workload1. But when rewritten them with ALLOW policy shown below the access from workload2 to workload1 succeeded.

I wonder why is that as the two rules should be equivalent (taken from https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/security/authorization-policy/#Rule where Fields in the source are ANDed together.)

```yaml
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name:  ingress-policy
  namespace: foo
spec:
 selector:
   matchLabels:
     app: workload1
 action: DENY
 rules:
   - from:
     - source:
        notPrincipals: ["cluster.local/ns/foo/sa/workload2"]
     - source:
        notPrincipals: ["cluster.local/ns/foo/sa/workload3"]
---

apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: ingress-policy
  namespace: foo
spec:
 selector:
   matchLabels:
     app: workload1
 action: ALLOW
 rules:
   - from:
     - source:
        Principals: ["cluster.local/ns/foo/sa/workload2"]
     - source:
        Principals: ["cluster.local/ns/foo/sa/workload3"]
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [istio documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/security/authorization-policy/):

> Istio Authorization Policy enables access control on workloads in the mesh.
>
> Authorization policy supports both allow and deny policies. **When allow and deny policies are used for a workload at the same time, the deny policies are evaluated first**. The evaluation is determined by the following rules:
>
> - If there are any DENY policies that match the request, deny the request.
> - If there are no ALLOW policies for the workload, allow the request.
> - If any of the ALLOW policies match the request, allow the request.
> - Deny the request.

So if deny policies are evaluated first. Your request could have been first denied and then allowed again. That's why your access from workload2 to workload1 succeeded after you add allow policy.

---

> My question was - it seems that the two AuthorizationPolicies are the same and I wanted to validate that as I get different behavior.

Yes, they are the same, if you delete 1 of the sources it's gonna work as desired.

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name:  ingress-policy
  namespace: foo
spec:
 selector:
   matchLabels:
     app: workload1
 action: DENY
 rules:
   - from:
     - source:
        notPrincipals: ["cluster.local/ns/foo/sa/workload2"]

apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: ingress-policy
  namespace: foo
spec:
 selector:
   matchLabels:
     app: workload1
 action: ALLOW
 rules:
   - from:
     - source:
        principals: ["cluster.local/ns/foo/sa/workload2"]
```

Test results.

```
DENY - > notPrincipals[workload2]     ->      workload2 -> 200, workload3 -> 403
DENY - > principals[workload2]        ->      workload2 -> 403, workload3 -> 200

ALLOW -> notPrincipals[workload2]     ->      workload2 -> 403, workload3 -> 200
ALLOW -> principals[workload2]        ->      workload2 -> 200, workload3 -> 403
```

---

If you want to add 2 sources, `workload2` and `workload3`, then use 1 source with few principals.

Use this:

```
 rules:
   - from:
     - source:
        notPrincipals: ["cluster.local/ns/foo/sa/workload2","cluster.local/ns/foo/sa/workload3"]
```

---

```
 rules:
   - from:
     - source:
        principals: ["cluster.local/ns/foo/sa/workload2","cluster.local/ns/foo/sa/workload3"]
```

instead of this:

```
rules:
  - from:
    - source:
       notPrincipals: ["cluster.local/ns/foo/sa/workload2"]
    - source:
       notPrincipals: ["cluster.local/ns/foo/sa/workload3"]
```

---

```
rules:
   - from:
     - source:
        principals: ["cluster.local/ns/foo/sa/workload2"]
     - source:
        principals: ["cluster.local/ns/foo/sa/workload3"]
```

Test results.

```
DENY - > notPrincipals[workload2,workload3]     ->      workload2 -> 200, workload3 -> 200
DENY - > Principals[workload2,workload3]        ->      workload2 -> 403, workload3 -> 403

ALLOW -> notPrincipals[workload2,workload3]     ->      workload2 -> 403, workload3 -> 403
ALLOW -> Principals[workload2,workload3]        ->      workload2 -> 200, workload3 -> 200
```

Comment: I did not add allow policy -- I replaced the deny with allow. Also, if request is denied by a policy it can not be allowed by another one.

Comment: Hi @Revital Eres, so what's the issue? If there is no deny why should it block the access from workload2 when it's allowed? About the second part `if request is denied by a policy it can not be allowed by another one.` I have tested that, and after I add deny and allow policy it worked like in below documentation, so if there is only deny it return `RBAC: access denied`, but if there is deny + allow policy it return `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`. Let me know if you want to see this example, maybe I'm wrong but I think it works as mentioned in above docs.

Comment: My question was - it seems that the two AuthorizationPolicies are the same and I wanted to validate that as I get different behavior.

Comment: Hi Revital! Sorry but at first i didn't understand you, I reproduced your case and find a way to fix this, now it works the way you wanted it to work. Take a look at my edited answer.