# Change istio authorization policy in Azure AKS

Tags: jwt, istio, azure-aks

I am having an issue with authentication using istio in Azure AKS. As far as I can tell I am generating a valid token but I get a 403 error.

The istio authorization config for the app is :

```
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: entitlements-jwt-authz
  namespace: osdu
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: entitlements-azure
  action: DENY
  rules:
    - from:
        - source:
            notRequestPrincipals: ["*"]
      to:
        - operation:
            notPaths: ["/",
                       "*/v2/api-docs",
                       "*/swagger-resources","*/swagger-ui.html",
                       "*/actuator/health",
                       "/entitlements/v1/swagger-resources/*",
                       "/entitlements/v1/webjars/*"]
```

I want to try and change this policy to just allow so I can try and isolate it to be a token issue but I am not sure how to change this policy as kubernetes is not something I am experienced with. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

I am not sure if I have given enough information so please ask if need more.

Thanks
Mike

Comment: What should this authorization policy do? It you want to just change it to `ALLOW` then the only thing you need to change is the `action`. If you want to change the whole AuthorizationPolicy from deny to allow, but you want to keep doing the same operations, then you would have to change `action`,  `source` and `operation`. So you would use `action: ALLOW`, `requestPrincipals: ["*"]` and `paths` . Additionally you can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64857337/11977760), I did some tests with AuthorizationPolicy  deny and allow. Let me know if that answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you have an `access_token` that is not compatible with istio's signature verification.

Go to [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) analyze your token. Does the `header` contain a `nonce`? If yes, that's the problem. Azure is not really transparent about this, but as far as I understand, the signature must be verified using JWKS and nonce, which istio can't.

For me, the solution was to change the scope from the default MS Graph scope to a custom one. You can create a scope in your app registration or use the default one: `<appId>/.default`, eg `abce-1234-ghkli-5677/.default`.