# Istio request.auth.claims[cognito:groups] is not working

Tags: amazon-cognito, istio

```
apiVersion: "security.istio.io/v1beta1"
kind: "RequestAuthentication"
metadata:
  name: "jwt-example"
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      istio: ingressgateway
  jwtRules:
    - issuer: "https://cognito-idp.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/ap-southeast-xxxxx"
      jwksUri: "https://cognito-idp.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/ap-southeast-xxxxx/.well-known/jwks.json"
```

and

```
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      istio: ingressgateway
  action: ALLOW
  rules:
    - from:
        - source:
            notRequestPrincipals: ["*"]
      to:
        - operation:
            paths: ["/api/v1/*"]
      when:
        - key: request.auth.claims[cognito:groups]
          values: ["testing"]
```

I've tried to use above code snippets as to allow access to use `/api/v1/*` if JWT token is based on `testing` group of AWS Cognito. Unfortunately, it's now working as showing `RBAC: access denied`. Please let me know how can I fix it?

Comment: If I understand [this](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authentication/authn-policy/#require-a-valid-token) correctly, you should use `DENY` with `notRequestPrincipals` or you use the opposite, `ALLOW` with `requestPrincipals`, so could you try to either change the action from `ALLOW` to `DENY` or change the source from `notRequestPrincipals` to `requestPrincipals`?  If any of that won't work could you try with `- key: request.auth.claims[groups]` instead of `request.auth.claims[cognito:groups]`? 1 more thing is that the key value should be under key, so you're missing 2 spaces.

Comment: even if I changed `request.auth.claims[groups]` and `ALLOW` or `DENY` with `requestPrincipals ` and `requestPrincipals `, it's not working at all. And I've added `RequestAuthentication` in my question as well.

Comment: @Jakub I've fixed issue based on your comment due to `requestPrincipals `. Can you post it as answer? I'll mark it as correct answer.

Comment: Happy it works for you! So it actually work with `action: ALLOW` and `requestPrincipals`, correct?

Comment: @Jakub yap, that one works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue

With your current AuthorizationPolicy you block every request with correct token with `403 RBAC: access denied`.

I have recently made [few tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64843547/istio-authorizationpolicy-deny-rule-question/64857337#64857337) with AuthorizationPolicy, it's worth taking a moment to understand how it works.

---

### Solution

As we discussed in comments, there are 2 ways to actually make this work.

With `action:ALLOW` and `requestPrincipals`

```
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      istio: ingressgateway
  action: ALLOW
  rules:
    - from:
        - source:
            requestPrincipals: ["*"]
```

or `action:DENY` and `NotRequestPrincipals`

```
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      istio: ingressgateway
  action: DENY
  rules:
    - from:
        - source:
            notRequestPrincipals: ["*"]
```

---

### Example

There is an example from [istio in action](https://livebook.manning.com/book/istio-in-action/chapter-8/v-9/343) book.

> Denying requests without JWT Tokens
>
> Let’s create an authorization policy that denies requests targeting the API Gateway without a JWT Token:

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
 name: app-gw-requires-jwt
 namespace: istio-system
spec:
 selector:
   matchLabels:
     app: istio-ingressgateway
 action: DENY
 rules:
 - from:
   - source:
       notRequestPrincipals: ["*"]
   to:
   - operation:
       hosts: ["apiserver.istioinaction.io"]
```

> This policy makes use of the property notRequestPrincipals and the "*" value, which means that the source matches for all requests that lack the request principal property. The Request Principal property gets its value from two claims that are extracted by the Request Authentication filter from the token and stored in filter metadata. The two claims being issuer and subject in the format iss/sub.